# create mysql database for user profile

Tags: mysql

I need to create a database in which there are 3 tables one is FRIENDS second is USERS third is PICTURES. I have one to many  relatioship between users and friends. There is one to many relationship between users and pictures table. I have red a question here with heading structuring a database for user profiles but it was lilbit confusing. They have userid as foreign key but i think picture id should be foreign key in users table.

One more question is, can we have 2 foreign keys in one table as i have one to many relationship of users table with pictures and friends table.  Sorry im not good in database. I just need some help.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many foreigh key realtions as you need. It makes sense to give PICTURES a userid if you want to link more than one picture to a user. If you want each user to have only one picture, you can give USERS a pictureid.

You can do both as well. Refer to USERS.pictureid if you want to see the main picture (like a portrait picture or an avatar) and allow PICTURES to have a userid so you can manage a set of pictures for each user as well. You can also give a user more than one pictureid, for instance a driverslicencepictureid, an avatarpictureid, a portraitpictureid etc, each being a foreign key to PICTURES.pictureid.

You might even consider the possibility to have each picture linked to more than one user, like facebook, which allows each user to be 'tagged' in multiple pictures, but also allows more than one user to be tagged in each picture.

In that case, you'll want a table to attach those two. Define a USERSPICTURES cross table that contains a userid and a pictureid. You can use this table to define cross links between users and pictures.

As I stated before, you can still give each user an id to specific picture in addition to the cross table.

The same goes for FRIENDS ofcourse. Every person can be a friend of every other person. So in this case you maybe could do with the FRIENDS table just storing the relationship between two USERS. Give the friends table a User1Id and a User2Id, and it allows to store the connection between two users (if that is what you want).

Comment: Golez thanks for the reply. If i give user id and user2id then which relation i have to define one to many i think as im just storing the relation. The other relation between picture and user is one to many as user can have multiple pictures. I have the following tables and relations.

Comment: It depends. If you go with my suggestion to redefine the FRIENDS table into some kind of a USERRELATION table, you actually create a many to many relation between users. There is a one to many relation between USERS.userid and RELATION.user1id, and a same relation between USERS.userid and RELATION.user2id. If you think FRIENDS are a different entity (not users per se), it might be beneficial to keep a FRIENDS table with a simple one to many relation between USERS.userid and FRIENDS.userid.

Comment: Golez thanks for the reply. If i give user id and user2id then which relation i have to define one to many i think as im just storing the relation. The other relation between picture and user is one to many as user can have multiple pictures. I have the following tables. Users: id, username, password, email, ip, port, pk id. Friends table contains id as pk, friendid. Pictures table contain id as pk, filepath, isprofile. Can you define keys in tables. I mean fk or unique key if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Pictures.UserId is FK, because any pictures can belong to one user only, but one user can have many pictures. Friends.User1Id is FK. One relation obviously is between exactly two people, that's why the relationships/friend table contains two userids, which is what might confuse you. Each relationship has only one user1, but any user can be user1 in many relationships. friends.user2id is the same type of relation: There is only one 'second person' in a relationship, but a user can be the second person in many relationships.

Comment: In addition: users.userid is PK (and therefor unique). The combination of userid1 and userid2 in friends is also unique. You could make this combination the primary key, but you could also create a relationshipid that is the primary key. I think it is a good practice to make the primary key a single field, but that's a matter of taste, I think. The practical advantages or disadvantages are probably irrelevant to you in this stage of your learning process.

Comment: Mind that even if you make the combination of user1 and user2 unique in the friends table, it is possible to create duplicate relations. If you want relationships to be able to be one way only, this is ok. If I am your friend, but you are not my friend, we could add a record with userid1 = MyId and userId2 = YourId, meaning that You are a friend of Me, but not vice versa. If relationships are always bidirectional, then, when your are my friend, I'm your friend too. In this case it might be inconvenient to store two records (userid1=myid, userid2=yourid  and  userid1=yourid, userid2=myid)....

Comment: That would take double the amount of data, so it's better to just store one record which basically means that user1 and user2 are friends. It is however possible to store a second record, which the userids switched, that basically means the same thing, but is different to the unique constraint check. You'll need to prevent that. I think this can easiest be done by creating a second constraint that requires userid2 to be greater than userid1. This prevent saving the same relationship and also prevents a user to become friends with themselves.

Comment: Golez thanks alot for your detailed answer. Whay do you mean by second contraint? let suppose my id is userid1 = 12 and you userid2 = 11 and i send a request to you and you accept my request in this case the record will not add in Friend table as you said userid2 should be grater than userid1?

Comment: When a record in Friends represents a mutual friendship, you wouldn't wat to store a record with userid1=12 and userid2=11 when you already got a record with userid1=11 and userid2=12, because they essentially mean the same thing. When you make a constraint that won't allow user2 to be less or equal to user1 you prevent this. You can build some logic that always inserts the lower number into userid1, but it may be better to build a trigger to do that. Another possibility is to skip the constraint and instead build a trigger that performs a query using the two inserted userids in reverse order.

Comment: I think the method of swapping id's will perform slightly faster, but the option using the query may less confusing. I think both solutions will work fine in preventing semantically duplicate records, but the actual choice to which solution is yours to make.

Comment: i have found an example database which is as follows. Please can you tell me which one is foreign key in this example. Because i have some confusion. Friends ( `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `providerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `requestId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `status` binary(1) NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`), UNIQUE KEY `Index_3` (`providerId`,`requestId`),
  KEY `Index_2` (`providerId`,`requestId`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='providerId is the Id of the users who wish to be friend with';

Comment: Users( `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL , `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL , `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '', `date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `authenticationTime` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `userKey` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', `IP` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '', `port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`), UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`username`), KEY `Index_3` (`authenticationTime`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: It looks like those tables are not related at all. I think the example is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks Golez, Can you tell me what they have defined in Users tables PRIMARY KEY (Id), UNIQUE KEY Index_2 (username), KEY Index_3 (authenticationTime)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; same as in Friends table.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to creat some sort of facebook 'friends' functionality then you need to reference the same table. For instance your USERS table could look like this:

(**userID**, name, email, friends,)

the friends field could then reference lots of the users'friends' by listing their relevent (userID)'s like this:

"23, 345, 34, 34, 23"

All in the same field. Any functions you need to write to list friends can then use this with an explode() to gather friend details.

Finally, yes it is possible to have 2 foreign keys in a table, you can have as many as you need.

Altenatively, something more scalable would be to have the following tables in your DB.

USERS
FRIENDS
PICTURES

The friends table would then list the relationships between two users like this:

FRIENDS TABLE

user1 = 34 <---this is a foreign key referencing the userID from USERS table
user2 = 44 <---this is a foreign key referencing the userID from USERS table

Comment: Grant thanks for the reply. Please have a look at my above comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two foreign keys in one table, although based on your description, you won't. Friends will have a Users FK and Pictures will have a Users FK. And that's it for FKs.

There are questions to be raised about your schema to begin with (e.g., if users are friends with users, their friends are still users, so friendships should be established through a many-to-many link table like Friendships), but based on your description, you should be covered in terms of FKs because you don't have 2 FKs in one table.